# Symfony2.8 -> 3.3 Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Extension\DependencyInjectionExtension::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in

Tags: php, symfony

I have updated symfony 2.8 -> 3.3

Now Top page looks working.
However when I load the page where uses form builder I burped into this error.

> Type error: Argument 3 passed to
> Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Extension\DependencyInjectionExtension::__construct()
> must be of the type array, object given, called in
> /Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myapp/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php
> on line 1325

I think this is related to service container though, I can’t figure out where should I fix.

What I am doing is like this below

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$reqDoc = new reqDoc();
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($reqDoc)
```

error messages is  below

> DependencyInjectionExtension->__construct(object(appDevDebugProjectContainer), array('Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType'
> =>object(RewindableGenerator), 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType'
> => object(RewindableGenerator), 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType'
> => object(RewindableGenerator), 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType'
> => object(RewindableGenerator)), object(RewindableGenerator), null,array('sonata_type_admin'
> => 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\AdminType', 'sonata_type_model' => 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\ModelType', 'sonata_type_model_list' =>
> 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\ModelTypeList',
> 'sonata_type_model_reference' =>
> 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\ModelReferenceType',
> 'sonata_type_model_hidden' =>
> 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\ModelHiddenType',
> 'sonata_type_model_autocomplete' =>
> 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\ModelAutocompleteType',
> 'sonata_type_native_collection' =>
> 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\CollectionType',
> 'sonata_type_choice_field_mask' =>
> 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\ChoiceFieldMaskType',
> 'sonata_type_filter_number' =>
> 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\Filter\NumberType',
> 'sonata_type_filter_choice' =>
> 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\Filter\ChoiceType',
> 'sonata_type_filter_default' =>
> 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\Filter\DefaultType',
> 'sonata_type_filter_date' =>
> 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\Filter\DateType',
> 'sonata_type_filter_date_range' =>
> 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\Filter\DateRangeType',
> 'sonata_type_filter_datetime' =>
> 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\Filter\DateTimeType',
> 'sonata_type_filter_datetime_range' =>
> 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\Filter\DateTimeRangeType', 'tab' =>
> 'Mopa\Bundle\BootstrapBundle\Form\Type\TabType',
> 'sonata_block_service_choice' =>
> 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Form\Type\ServiceListType',
> 'sonata_type_container_template_choice' =>
> 'Sonata\BlockBundle\Form\Type\ContainerTemplateType', 'form' =>
> 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType',
> 'birthday' =>
> 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\BirthdayType',
> 'checkbox' =>
> 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType',
> 'choice' =>
> 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType',
> 'collection' =>
> 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType',
> 'country' =>
> 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CountryType', 'date'
> => 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType', 'datetime' =>
> 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType',
> 'email' =>
> 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType', 'file'
> => 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType', 'hidden' =>
> 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType',
> 'integer' =>
> 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType',
> 'language' =>
> 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\LanguageType',
> 'locale' =>
> 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\LocaleType', 'money'
> => 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\MoneyType', 'number' =>
> 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType',
> 'password' =>
> 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType',
> 'percent' =>
> 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PercentType',
> 'radio' =>
> 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RadioType',
> 'repeated' =>
> 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType',
> 'search' =>
> 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SearchType',
> 'textarea' =>
> 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType',
> 'text' => 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType',
> 'time' => 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TimeType',
> 'timezone' =>
> 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TimezoneType', 'url'
> => 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\UrlType', 'button' =>
> 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ButtonType',
> 'submit' =>
> 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType', 'reset'
> => 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ResetType', 'currency' =>
> 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CurrencyType',
> 'entity' => 'Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType',
> 'sonata_type_immutable_array' =>
> 'Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\ImmutableArrayType',
> 'sonata_type_boolean' =>
> 'Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\BooleanType',
> 'sonata_type_collection' =>
> 'Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\CollectionType',
> 'sonata_type_translatable_choice' =>
> 'Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\TranslatableChoiceType',
> 'sonata_type_date_range' =>
> 'Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\DateRangeType',
> 'sonata_type_datetime_range' =>
> 'Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\DateTimeRangeType',
> 'sonata_type_date_picker' =>
> 'Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\DatePickerType',
> 'sonata_type_datetime_picker' =>
> 'Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\DateTimePickerType',
> 'sonata_type_date_range_picker' =>
> 'Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\DateRangePickerType',
> 'sonata_type_datetime_range_picker' =>
> 'Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\DateTimeRangePickerType',
> 'sonata_type_equal' => 'Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\EqualType',
> 'sonata_type_color_selector' =>
> 'Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\ColorSelectorType'), array('form'
> =>array('sonata.admin.form.extension.field', 'mopa_bootstrap.form.type_extension.help',
> 'mopa_bootstrap.form.type_extension.legend',
> 'mopa_bootstrap.form.type_extension.error',
> 'mopa_bootstrap.form.type_extension.widget',
> 'mopa_bootstrap.form.type_extension.horizontal',
> 'mopa_bootstrap.form.type_extension.widget_collection',
> 'mopa_bootstrap.form.type_extension.tabbed',
> 'form.type_extension.form.http_foundation',
> 'form.type_extension.form.validator', 'form.type_extension.csrf',
> 'form.type_extension.form.data_collector'), 'choice'
> =>array('sonata.admin.form.extension.choice'), 'button' => array('mopa_bootstrap.form.type_extension.button'), 'date' =>array('mopa_bootstrap.form.type_extension.date'), 'repeated' => array('form.type_extension.repeated.validator'), 'submit' =>array('form.type_extension.submit.validator')), array())
> in var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php (line 1325)

Comment: Are you sure your installed SonataCoreBundle version is compatible with Symfony 3.3? Maybe you have to upgrade Sonata as well.

Comment: I am using sonata-project/core-bundle 3.1.2. https://packagist.org/packages/sonata-project/core-bundle?query=sonata-project%2Fcore-bundle%203.1.2#3.1.2

Comment: I version up to 3.9.0 it solved problem. thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my answer mentioned in the comments:

Probably you have to upgrade your `SonataCoreBundle` dependency version as well. Maybe this one is not compatible with Symfony 3.3.